# php loop through scandir to output different filename

Tags: php, mysql, loops, scandir

I am attempting to generate a list of SQL commands that i will later insert.  The only part at this time I seem to be stuck on is looping the file name.  I need my scandir to loop through the nofilter directory and change $image each time a new line or sql query is given.  I have the code and output below.  Essentially no sql query should have the same $image being echo'd into it

```
for ($i=1351314000; $i<=1351400400; $i+= 14400) {
    $images = scandir("/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/nofilter/");
    foreach($images as $image) {

    }

//copy file over from no filter
$orig = "/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/nofilter/".$image."";
$dest =   "/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/".$image."";
//copy($orig, $dest);


//output
  echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
echo $image;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "

INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` (
`id` ,
`status_message` ,
`link` ,
`photo_url` ,
`status_name` ,
`status_caption` ,
`status_description` ,
`uid` ,
`page_id` ,
`access_token` ,
`post_to` ,
`status_type` ,
`schedule_type` ,
`is_process` ,
`process_time` ,
`process_at` ,
`display_time` ,
`created_by`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/". $image ."', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '". $i ."', NULL , '". $i ."', '100000103637895'
);
";

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

 }
```

The output looks like this

```
The number is 1351314000 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351314000', NULL , '1351314000', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351328400 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351328400', NULL , '1351328400', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351342800 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351342800', NULL , '1351342800', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351357200 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351357200', NULL , '1351357200', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351371600 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351371600', NULL , '1351371600', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351386000 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351386000', NULL , '1351386000', '100000103637895' );

The number is 1351400400 8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg


INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` ( `id` , `status_message` , `link` , `photo_url` , `status_name` , `status_caption` , `status_description` , `uid` , `page_id` , `access_token` , `post_to` , `status_type` , `schedule_type` , `is_process` , `process_time` , `process_at` , `display_time` , `created_by` ) VALUES ( NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/8120925654_4041b7c50f_o.jpg', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '1351400400', NULL , '1351400400', '100000103637895' );
```

Comment: Is that all, or have you got more?

Comment: What's this loop all about? `for ($i=1351314000; $i<=1351400400; $i+= 14400) {`

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos Those are UNIX time stamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on  your comment, why not do it like this instead?

```
<php
$time = time();
$images = scandir("/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/nofilter/");
foreach($images as $image) {
    if ($image == '.' || $image == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $time += 14400; //add 4 hours every interval

    //copy file over from no filter
    $orig = "/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/nofilter/".$image."";
    $dest =   "/home/fb/public_html/post/uploads/".$image."";
    //copy($orig, $dest);


    //output
      echo "The number is " . $time . "<br />";
    echo $image;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    echo "

    INSERT INTO `fb_fb`.`postcron_schedule` (
    `id` ,
    `status_message` ,
    `link` ,
    `photo_url` ,
    `status_name` ,
    `status_caption` ,
    `status_description` ,
    `uid` ,
    `page_id` ,
    `access_token` ,
    `post_to` ,
    `status_type` ,
    `schedule_type` ,
    `is_process` ,
    `process_time` ,
    `process_at` ,
    `display_time` ,
    `created_by`
    )
    VALUES (
    NULL , '', '', '/home/fb/public_html/post/includes/../uploads/". $image ."', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0', '135031429962113', 'AAAGLZAMh7YSUBALRMCW60Rdol1kD80ZBNymqkgyQfBXDour2KsvVWKFcnZB9cU9OSLRMQjnEuKHZCTNoTZC4jf9GFtMU11BTD8JZAUFl0EVgZDZD', 'page', 'photo', 'schedule', '0', '". $time ."', NULL , '". $time ."', '100000103637895'
    );
    ";

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

 }
```

Comment: Great if you like the answers on stackoverflow its usually common to accept them or upvote the answer

Comment: Better to delete the `.` and `..` files you can use `$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));`

Comment: that works.  how hard would it be to use rand() to randomize the $image variable going in the sql query

Comment: @TaylorReed You can use shuffle() on the original $images array just before going into the foreach. like so: `shuffle($images);` ... then next line `foreach(....` See this for details http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up your braces:

```
// does nothing
for( $images as $image ) {

}
```

I started formatting your code and once it was formatted, you could see that one of your loops doesn't do anything.  If you format code then it's easier to see these sorts of things.

Your outer loop uses the `$images` variable and then there's an inner loop (see above) that does nothing but defines the `$image` variable and then you're getting unexpected results because you're then using this variable.